# Safe handling of user password for third party login

Tags: python, streamlit

For the access to openBIS, an electronic lab notebook, I need to supply username and password for the login. In a python web interface I'm using a module (pybis) to access openBIS, and I'd like the users to use their own credentials to login. However, I would need to ask for the user credentials and pass them to the login method in clear text. Is there a save way to do this? Even though I don't need the username and password permanently, since pybis returns a session token which is used afterwards, I'd still have to handle username and password in clear text, which would exist in memory for a short time. Or is that uncritical, if I delete the variable right after using it?
Maybe something like this would work safely?

```py
import streamlit as st
username = st.text_input("Enter a username")
password = st.text_input("Enter a password", type="password")
pybis.login(username, password) # for simplicity, the real code is slightly different. Returns session token, which is used afterwards.
del username
del password
```